# Resume suspended map when verifying before share?

Tags: wargroove

In Wargroove, you can share maps with the community, but first you have to click the "verify" button and beat the map, in order to prove that the map is in fact beatable.

I made a very long scenario map that takes several hours to beat. It's difficult to set enough time aside to beat the map in one sitting.

While playing a map to verify it, you can open the menu and choose the "Suspend" option to save & quit the map. However, after suspending the map, clicking the "verify" button again starts the map over from the beginning rather than resuming where you left off.

Is there any way to resume a suspended verification session?